# Subquery within Subquery is not working in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, bigdata

I have a complexed query, I am giving the simplified version of it here. Would like to know why it is not working.

```
select * from ((select 1) t1 union (select 2) t2);
```

Getting the below error

```
NoViableAltException(290@[147:5: ( ( Identifier LPAREN )=> partitionedTableFunction | tableSource | subQuerySource | virtualTableSource )])
at org.antlr.runtime.DFA.noViableAlt(DFA.java:158)
at org.antlr.runtime.DFA.predict(DFA.java:144)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_FromClauseParser.fromSource(HiveParser_FromClauseParser.java:3654)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_FromClauseParser.joinSource(HiveParser_FromClauseParser.java:1836)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_FromClauseParser.fromClause(HiveParser_FromClauseParser.java:1488)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.fromClause(HiveParser.java:44869)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.singleSelectStatement(HiveParser.java:42035)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.selectStatement(HiveParser.java:41720)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.regularBody(HiveParser.java:41657)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.queryStatementExpressionBody(HiveParser.java:40710)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.queryStatementExpression(HiveParser.java:40586)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.execStatement(HiveParser.java:1529)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.statement(HiveParser.java:1065)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:201)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:166)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:418)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:312)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1201)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1296)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1127)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1115)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:220)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:172)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:383)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:775)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:693)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:628)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

FAILED: ParseException line 1:15 cannot recognize input near '(' '(' 'select' in from source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1

Unlike some databases, Hive does not accept brackets around a query.
E.g. `select 1` is a valid query In hive, but not `(select 1)`.

P.s.
Even databases that accept brackets around queries, do not accept aliases for these queries when combined by UNION.
E.g. `(select 1) union (select 2)` is a valid query in some databases, but not `(select 1) t1 union (select 2) t2`

#### 2

Unlike some databases, Hive requires an alias for a sub-query.
E.g. `select * from (select 1) t` is a valid query In hive, but not `select * from (select 1)`

---

The right way to write the OP query would be -
`select * from (select 1 union select 2) t;`

---

```
+-----+
| _c0 |
+-----+
|   1 |
|   2 |
+-----+
```

Comment: I gave it a try and got an exception with the last query. Please check again.

Comment: Tested on Hive 2.1 (When I'm posting results, it is always a copy-paste from an executed code). I'm guessing you have an issue  with the UNION which is supported only from version 1.2.0. Try UNION ALL instead.

Comment: Yup, that did it. I am using 1.1.0. I presume `union` isn't supported?

Comment: I have added the version information to my previous comment :-) In any case - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Union